# Double Integral with Polar Cordinates

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

$$ \int \:\int _r^{ }\:\:x^2+y^2\:dxdy $$

The question is asking me to change these **cartesian** coordinates to **polar** coordinates which I have been unable to do, and then it provides me with R is bound in the first region by $ y = 0$ and $y = x$  and the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 4$.

Can someone please help me understand this

Answer (score 0):

Your domain in polar coordinates is

$$R=\{(r,\theta)\,|\,0<\theta<\pi/4\,,\,0<r<2\,\}$$
and then your integral reads

$$\int\int_R x^2+y^2 dx\,dy=\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^2 r^3\,dr\,d\theta=\pi$$

Comment: How would evaluation work and can you give me a step by step of how you got here

Comment: Which "evaluation work"? Can you be more precise?

Comment: If you had to evaluate the double integral with the bounds provided by R in the question

Comment: That is, in cartesian coordenates?

Comment: Is it possible to do in polar coordinates, if it isn't then cartesian

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand you. My answer is about polar coordenates, then what do you want to do?

Comment: I want to evaluate the double integral now

Comment: And the value es $\pi$. What's the problem? If you don't say what is the problem in my explanation, I can't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Area element $ dx\cdot dy$ changes to $ r d \theta \cdot dr\,$
$$\int_0^2 \int_{\pi/4} ^{\pi/2} r^2 r dr\, d\theta $$

Limits are separable, $r$ is not a function of $\theta$

$$ \dfrac{r^4}{4}\big|_0^2 \cdot \theta \big|_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}=\,\pi$$

[image]

Comment: How would I evaluate it with these polar cords tho, I've been trying to do this for an hour

Comment: Haven't you shaded the wrong region?  Since the problem says the regions is bounded by $y=0$ and $y=x$ shouldn't we have $0\leq\theta\leq\frac\pi4$?

Comment: @userThroughout This is in polar coordinates.  I don't understand what you are asking for.